# How to store the result of some operations on Integer in to a different data type in java

Tags: java, casting, floating-point

So I have two Integers, I am finding their median by adding them and then dividing them by 2. I want to store their floating result. So I am doing -

```
float res = (float) (num1 + num2) / 2;
```

Sometimes this expression return 0.0 for non zero inputs. I think the problem is num1 and and num2 range can vary to the full spectrum of 32 bits. So when both are in the high spectrum, float cast breaks as its not able to store the results and returns 0.0.

I don't want to do `(float)num1/2 + (float)num2/2` as I might loose decimal precision during this.

Any pointers on how can I handle this scenario.

Comment: Use `double` instead of `float` and cast before dividing?

Comment: Be aware that there are 2^32 possible `int` values and also 2^32 possible `float` values.  That implies that there are some `int` values that can't be represented correctly in a `float`.  So if `num1` and `num2` can be anywhere in the gamut of `int` values, your endeavour is doomed to failure.

Comment: The float cast wouldn't break them. What's happening is that you're doing integer division. You can do num1/2d or num/2f and it won't mess everything up as badly. But, really convert num1 and num2 to doubles and do all the math in double. Seems like the best way to keep all your bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending what your actual requirements are, float may not do the trick either.

For a correct result try this:

```
int num 1 = ...
int num 2 = ...
double avg = (((long) num1) + num2) / 2D;
```

The point is to add the int's as long's (cast one to long, the other is cast automatically because long + int causes a widening conversion). This avoids a possible integer overflow when the sum of both ints is larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE (or smaller than Integer.MIN_VALUE).

Then divide by two, by suffixing the 2 literal as double literal an explicit cast is not needed. Again for the division this causes an implicit widening conversion where long / double = double.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) type for this purpose.

```
int num1 = 1;
int num2 = 2;
BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(num1 + num2);
BigDecimal result = sum.divide(new BigDecimal(2));
```

In case `num1` and `num2` are the floating-point types, use

```
BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(num1).add(new BigDecimal(num2));
```

Then you can get any type from result, for example

```
double v = result.doubleValue();
```

Comment: Why to use Class Type although you can simply use primitive type?

Comment: @Yahya Because the problem is that the primitive types are not good enough. The class type is more reliable at the cost of extra overhead, hence why it exists.

Comment: It's quite oftenly asked question. Primitive types are not strict enough to keep floating values. Try, for example, summ of 0.1d+0.1d+0.1d and the result will be something like 0.30000000000000004

Comment: Any int / 2D gives a perfectly accurate double result.

Comment: BigDecimal is _way_ overkill for this, as Durandal has correctly pointed out.

Comment: @Tezra *"Because the problem is that the primitive types are not good enough"*, prove it please!

Comment: @arsen_adzhiametov What are you talking about! `num1` and  `num2` are *INTEGERS* and OP concerns about the precision of result *AFTER* division! The example you mentioned in the comment is not what you're looking for!

Comment: @Yahya from op `I think the problem is num1 and and num2 range can vary to the full spectrum of 32 bits` Int.MAX+Int.MAX is not suitable for primitives unless you accept rounding errors. However, this is **A** solution, not **THE ONLY** solution. So each user can evaluate the pros and cons of this solution for themselves.

Comment: @Tezra *"`Int.MAX+Int.MAX` is not suitable for primitives unless you accept rounding errors"* give me an example !

Comment: @Yahya TECHNICALLY  Int.Max*2 is 33 bits (32+1). So it can be stored in a double without error (52 bits without sign or exponent) but not a float (23). But once you start counting bits, clearly you have a problem. For non time critical code, I would recommend the more correct BigDecimal. For time sensitive code, the more performant double. I am just saying, there is a good reason BigDecimal exists, and it's programmer discretion if that is what they should use. (If you are optimizing for a problem you don't have, that is also a sign you have a problem)

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple test, and as I *mentioned* in my comment, you can cast it with `double` or `long` (as another option):

```
public class Casting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // the maximum positive value for a signed binary integer
        int num1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
        int num2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        float resFloat = ((float)num1 + num2) / 2;
        double resDouble = ((double)num1 + num2) / 2;
        double resLong = ((long)num1 + num2) / 2;

        // Testing [Expected Result is 2147483647]
        System.out.println("Size: " + Integer.SIZE); // in bits (on my machine)
        System.out.println("Max Value: " + Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.printf("Float Cast: %f\n", resFloat);
        System.out.printf("Double Cast: %f\n", resDouble);
        System.out.printf("Long Cast: %f\n", resLong);  
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Size: 32
Max Value: 2147483647
Float Cast: 2147483648.000000
Double Cast: 2147483647.000000
Long Cast: 2147483647.000000
```

Comment: This is just a less complete version of @Durandal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44315312/6893866).... Do you have any additional information to add to that? Otherwise, this should be kept in the comments.

Comment: @Tezra How is that? Are you talking from your mind or just wanna comment anything after you failed to explain "why should use Class although you can simply use primitive type" *To Solve* this problem in particular? And by the way, I was the first one commented for casting and changing to double FYI!

Comment: No, I'm just saying, this answer was posted after, so you probably should have just linked the code in the comments where it was relevant.... And I made my case. If you don't agree, that is your opinion. I'm just suggesting "this probably should have been a comment instead of an answer", not "you're wrong". (Technically, I'm also saying your right since I linked the accepted answer)